# Why SwaggerForOcelot not load services swagge endpoints .NET 6?

Tags: .net, swagger, microservices, swagger-ui, ocelot

I'm testing .NET 6 rc.1 and I try to setup a project with microservices structure.
For now I have 2 project:

1. AuthenticationAPI
2. APIGateway

I have created some endpoints in the Authentication API project and setup the APIGateway ocelot.json file (in my case I have created a file ocelot.authentication.json).

I trying some solutions but nothing seem to work.
My first solution is to add the SwaggerEndPoints key in the ocelot.authentication.json but this not work because when the ocelot.json is generated don't read the key on the main ocelot.json file.
I've try to put the SwaggerEndPoints key in application.json but this not work.
Now I trying to add manually the endpoint on Program.cs and this work but maybe there is some problem with the service swagger configuration path because I need to set an alternative path like /auth/swagger instead of /swagger. If I try to configure the full path (http://localhost:5200/swagger) there is a cors problem.

So, how can I configure the service swagger for a custom endpoint or configure the SwaggerEndPoints in the file?

**Swagger on AuthenticationAPI**

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(setup =>
{
    setup.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Authentication API v1");
   
});
```

**Swagger on APIGateway with Minimal API**

```
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddOcelot(builder.Environment);
builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddSwaggerForOcelot(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddMvc();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwaggerForOcelotUI(options =>
{
    options.DownstreamSwaggerEndPointBasePath = "/swagger";
    options.PathToSwaggerGenerator = "/swagger/docs";
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("https://localhost:5201/swagger", 
    "Authentication API");
}).UseOcelot().Wait();

app.Run();
```

In this case I have the CORS error:
[CORS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EPen.png)

Thanks for any suggestions!

**UPDATE**

All ocelot.*.json files now are in the Configuration folder.
I have added the ocelot.SwaggerEndPoints.json with swagger configuration and updated the initialization:

**Program.cs**

```
using MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddOcelotWithSwaggerSupport(options =>
{
    options.Folder = "Configuration";
});
builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddSwaggerForOcelot(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddMvc();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwaggerForOcelotUI(options =>
{
    options.PathToSwaggerGenerator = "/swagger/docs";
}).UseOcelot().Wait();

app.Run();
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: I have solved by moving the merging files into a folder and by adding the ocelot.SwaggerEndPoints.json file

Comment: Are you using SwaggerEndpoints configuration file ? if so how you manage to change url per environment